# Prevent psql from printing execution time at bottom of output

Tags: formatting, output, psql, execution-time

Here's the output of `psql -q -t -c "SELECT 1;"`

```
        1

Time: 0.379 ms
```

It should be possible, but I can't find a way to prevent the execution time from being printed at the bottom - is there a way to prevent it? *(Note: I'm already specifying the quiet mode and tuples only flags, to no avail)*

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-A` ignores the `.psqlrc` file and does the trick